# repeat a group of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input to be matched by a regex:

```
1.1.1.1
1.01.1.1
01.01.091.01
1.10.100.0010
```

So I have allways four groups consisting of digits. While the first three ones should match, the last one should not.

So I wrote this regex:

```
^(\d*[1-9]+\.){4}$
```

In general this regex should return all those strings where any of the digits in any of the groups is *not* followed by a zero. Or more easily: I want to not match all numbers with trailing zeros.

However this doesn´t match anything. [`regex1010.com`](https://regex101.com) tells this:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
>   capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
>   use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

But when I add a further capturing group I get the same message:

```
^((\d*[1-9]+\.)){4}$
```

The same applies to a non-capturing group:

```
^(?:\d*[1-9]+\.){4}$
```

Of course I could just write the same group four times, but that´s fairly clumsy and hard to read.

Comment: @VadimKotov look the tags, it's a question about regex but using c#.

Comment: None of your regexes even _contain_ the dot... and even if they did, there's no such thing as automatic "in-between" functionality.

Comment: @Nyerguds I edited the question to also contain the dot

Comment: @HimBromBeere Apparently nobody noticed the actual point of the question.

Comment: Now you're matching "n.n.n.n.", with a dot at the end, instead of the "n.n.n.n" you want. See my answer for the correct explanation. And who is downvoting all these answers?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Me neither... I have to admit I didn´t put everything into the question right attracting many answers that were based on whrong assumptions. Editing the question again and again seems whrong to me however as it will invalidate previous answers.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Can you blame people? The point of the question was exactly the thing he _forgot_ in the regexes in his question.

Comment: @Nyerguds Even the very first revision of the question contained *"In general this regex should return all those strings where any of the digits in any of the groups is not followed by a zero."* And still there were four obviously wrong and almost identical answers. I know the missing dot part didn't help, but that's why you ask for details before providing an answer.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer But as he said in the answer he made himself, that wasn't the point. That's the part he already got right. The dots were the problem, because they mean the pattern isn't a repetition of 4 at all. It's just really bad form to downvote answers despite them containing the requested information.

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes, I know. His regex was wrong and pointing out that issue in a comment would be the right thing to do, but providing an answer that solves one issue and completely ignores everything else is not helpful at all.

Comment: Very well, edited my answer to address that detail. All I'm saying was that the assumptions on which I based my answer were _not_ wrong.

Comment: @Nyerguds To be clear I didn´t downvote any answer.

Comment: Nope, I did - because it was wrong (and the others still are).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Being right or wrong isn't what these votes are about. Hover your mouse over the up/down arrow, and you'll see the criterion is _usefulness_. Even answers that are _not_ completely correct can be _useful_.

Comment: I don't think wrong answers are "useful". I've retracted the vote because you corrected the mistake. And since you were the 5th person to mention the dot that alone wasn't anything new either.

Comment: @FelipeOriani there was no c# tag when I've asked, that's why I posted my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never specify the dot in your patterns. What you ask for is, in fact, *not* a repetition of four, it is a specific single pattern of four numbers separated with dots.

```
^(\d*[1-9]+\.\d*[1-9]+\.\d*[1-9]+\.\d*[1-9]+)$
```

The only thing in there you could consider a repetition is the "number + dot" part, but then you repeat that *three* times and add another number. Then the regex would become this:

```
^((\d*[1-9]+\.){3}\d*[1-9]+)$
```

However, your third line contains a space at the end, so you may want to add extra checks to trim those off.

Comment: The space was a typo. I edited then question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others the dot is the point, so we have three identical groups and one without the dot.

So this regex does it for me:

```
(?:\d*[1-9]\.){3}(?:\d*[1-9])
```

Comment: Um. That's what I answered. I just didn't bother with the specific `\d*[1-9]+` part, because, as you said, _the dot is the point_.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your regex is by not including the `.` your regex fails to find four matches of digits because they always have dots in between.'

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZCdj3Y/2) instead:

```
(?:(\d*[1-9])\.?){4}
```

Comment: Care to explain the down-vote? It matches the first three and not the last, that's the best I could read out of your question.

Comment: Try `1111` - the optional dot isn't helping

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that.